# How to display pair plot from text data

Tags: python, pandas

I have txt data form like the following. I would like to plot to compare the couples T(predict) - T(real) and E(predict)-E(real).

```
# T(predi) E(predict)       # T(real) E(real) 
1 T= 601. E= -.72462983E+03 1 T= 601. E= -.72462497E+03
2 T= 602. E= -.72464801E+03 2 T= 602. E= -.72464965E+03
3 T= 608. E= -.72465664E+03 3 T= 607. E= -.72465453E+03
4 T= 619. E= -.72466672E+03 4 T= 614. E= -.72465770E+03
5 T= 632. E= -.72467811E+03 5 T= 622. E= -.72466228E+03
6 T= 646. E= -.72468973E+03 6 T= 629. E= -.72466767E+03
7 T= 657. E= -.72470168E+03 7 T= 637. E= -.72467402E+03
8 T= 663. E= -.72471276E+03 8 T= 644. E= -.72468087E+03
9 T= 661. E= -.72472269E+03 9 T= 648. E= -.72468913E+03
10 T= 652. E= -.72473076E+03 10 T= 648. E= -.72469576E+03
11 T= 639. E= -.72461744E+03 11 T= 645. E= -.72470063E+03
12 T= 622. E= -.72461563E+03 12 T= 638. E= -.72470469E+03
13 T= 604. E= -.72461422E+03 13 T= 627. E= -.72470813E+03
14 T= 586. E= -.72461309E+03 14 T= 614. E= -.72471141E+03
15 T= 570. E= -.72461174E+03 15 T= 600. E= -.72471497E+03
16 T= 556. E= -.72460997E+03 16 T= 587. E= -.72471740E+03
17 T= 547. E= -.72460840E+03 17 T= 574. E= -.72471902E+03
18 T= 544. E= -.72460811E+03 18 T= 565. E= -.72472163E+03
19 T= 547. E= -.72460976E+03 19 T= 560. E= -.72472417E+03
20 T= 554. E= -.72458790E+03 20 T= 561. E= -.72472707E+03
```

This code does not work. I wonder how to choose columns (3, 8) and columns (5,10) for the pair plot. Can anyone help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep='delimiter', 
                 header=None, engine='python')
print(df)
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
```

Expected Figure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read the text file with an actual delimiter, not the word "delimiter". In this case it's a single space.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=' ', header=None, engine='python')
```

Since you're interested in only 2 numerical columns, plot for only those two.

```
plot = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df[[2,7]], alpha=0.2)
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear explanation. I would like to have a figure like I have just edited.